# read multiple lines from file using csh scripting

Tags: c, unix

hi everyone want to write scripting(ksh) to read line by line from file which contains member data and needs to be send an email consecutively per line to same email address

This is how far I got:

```
js020:
setenv JS "js020"
jsbeg_msg.csh

# Input Files
setenv EMAIL_MSG_FILENAME "`gdg $DATADIR/abcemail -c`"

# Apply Overrides
source $SRCDIR/override.src

#Execute program
setenv SUBJECT " Recovery Notice"

for line in $(cat $EMAIL_MSG_FILENAME) 
do 
    echo "$line"
    echo "SENDING E-MAIL MESSAGE TO xxxx"
    execpgm.csh '/usr/ucb/mail -s "$SUBJECT"  xyz@abc.com < "$EMAIL_MSG_FILENAME"'
    if ($status != 0) then
         echo "Sending e-mail in Step " ${JS} " FAILED! "
         exit (-1)
    endif
done

# END OF JOB

eoj_msg.csh $0

exit(0)
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: @EagleRainbow thanks for your response below I have attached the job script I have tried it throws error saying "variable syntax"

Comment: js020:
setenv JS "js020"
jsbeg_msg.csh

# Input Files

setenv EMAIL_MSG_FILENAME "`gdg $DATADIR/abcemail -c`"

# Apply Overrides
source $SRCDIR/override.src
# Execute program

setenv SUBJECT " Recovery Notice"
setenv EMAILADDR "xyz@abc.com"
for line in $(cat $EMAIL_MSG_FILENAME) 
do 
echo "$line"
echo "SENDING E-MAIL MESSAGE TO SUMAN"
execpgm.csh '/usr/ucb/mail -s " Recovery Notice"  xyz@abc.com < "$EMAIL_MSG_FILENAME"'
if ($status != 0) then
echo "Sending e-mail in Step " ${JS} " FAILED! "
exit (-1)
endif
done

# END OF JOB
eoj_msg.csh $0
exit(0)

Comment: @EagleRainbow when I commented the loop and tried the remaining portion it works fine

Comment: Please add your coding properly formatted to the original question; you are allowed to edit it. Moreover, pleas etry to describe where you get stuck exactly. This will help other's to be able to help you

Comment: @EagleRainbow I am sorry for your inconvenience this is the first time I am posting in the site I wanted to know is the loop syntax I tried above is correct or not because it throws me error saying variable syntax error.. thanks in advance

Comment: That's exactly why I am here :) I try to guide you... and let's try to improve the formatting of your question a little...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach Lineread ("`cat $File_name`")

setenv myline "$Lineread"

execpgm.csh 'echo "$myline" | /usr/bin/mailx -s "Notice" xyz@abc.com'

if ($status != 0) then

echo "Sending e-mail in Step " ${JS} " FAILED! "

exit (-1)

endif

end

Comment: hi all I find one more issue I need to add footer saying do not reply to this message can anyone help me in doing this please